# I'm trying to take bundles on my HomeFragment but when i enter first, i got error

Tags: kotlin, bundle

I'm sending bundles to my Home Fragment at another fragments. But when the app opens at the first, gives me an error because app didnt takes any bundles at the first. By the way i'm sending and getting bundles like this;

```
//Sending
            val fragment = Notlar()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("categoryId", -99)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_kategoriler_to_notlar, bundle)

//Getting (On Home Fragment)
            categoryIdBundle = requireArguments().getInt("categoryId",-1)
```

I have tried something like;

```
try {
    categoryIdBundle = requireArguments().getInt("categoryId",-1)
} catch (e : Exception) {
    categoryIdBundle = -1
}
```

But even though it opens at the beginning, the bundles i send never come, so the catch block always works. What can i do at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **Safe Call Operator** in Kotlin `.?` to make sure if data is not null, and try this code to send data between fragments using bundle

```kotlin
// in the first fragment

findNavController().navigate(
    R.id.action_kategoriler_to_notlar,
    Bundle().apply {
        putInt("categoryId", -99)
    }
)

// in destination fragment
arguments?.getInt("categoryId", -1)?.let {
    // handle the result here ...
}
```

you can read more about safe call [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls), and about send bundle in navigation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#bundle)

Hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot :') I didnt think it can be that simple at the first :') Thanks for your help! :)